# Can you get wings in diablo 3 without collectors edition?

Tags: diablo-iii

Like the title says. Is there any of getting these? Can I trade with someone who has them or are they account bound?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to get wings without Collectors Edition. The wings are account bound.

Otherwise everybody would have them, because you get a new pair of wings on every new character.

Comment: Ahhhh poop. I figured there may be a hidden event/boss somewhere. Oh well hehe

Comment: And there'd be a market for selling said wings; create new character, get money, give wings.  Rinse and repeat ad nauseum.

Comment: That makes sense.

Comment: The same is true with the Discriminating Taste achievement. It is only attainable with the Collector's Edition.

Comment: And 2 dyes: `Bottled Cloud` and `Bottled Smoke` are only available for owners of Collector's Edition